# How can we restrict the user to a specific date format in the AWS tag policy?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, format, tags, policy

I am creating a Tag Policy in AWS. I need to develop a rule to restrict the value of one of the keys to a specific format.

I need the end user to enter the value in `yyyymmdd` format. How can I build the JSON policy to reflect this?

This is what I have so far. I am using it in
[image]

```
{
    "tags": {
        "DateCreated": {
            "tag_key": {
                "@@assign": "DateCreated"
            },
            "tag_value": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "yyyymmdd"
                ]
            }
        },
            "enforced_for": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "s3:bucket"               ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_example-tag-policies.html) saying that it supports arbitrary formats. It supports acceptable values (from a pre-defined list) or a single wildcard such as `*@example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I think tag policies do not support regex etc. to validate values so alternative solution would be using  AWS Config and writing a custom config policy rule by using Guard policy language or Lambda function.

Use proactive evaluation to restrict users to create tags which does adhere to set rules.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules.html